# Fingerstyle fingering economy - should I use pinky barre to avoid finger motion?

Tags: guitar, technique, fingerstyle-guitar

What would be optimal fingering for fretting hand while playing phrases like this one? Am I doing it correctly?

```
    4     1           
    4
    3  3     3  2  3  4  1

E|--9-----7--------------7--
B|--9-----------------9-----
G|--9--9-----9-----9--------
D|--------------------------
A|--------------------------
E|--0-----------9-----------
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        4     1           1*
        4
        3  3     3  2  3     3

    E|--9-----7-----------9-----  
    B|--9-----------------------  
    G|--9--9-----9-----9-----9--  
    D|--------------------------  
    A|--------------------------  
    E|--0-----------9-----------
```

Are you sure you entered that correctly? The asterisked note (first finger, C# note, 1st string) particularly awkward and is much more easily played by the 3rd or 4th finger for me.

Here is the fingering that feels most appropriate to me, although It's hard to tell what is best without knowing what comes before and after this section.

```
        3     1           4
        3
        3  3     3  2  3     3

    E|--9-----7-----------9-----
    B|--9-----------------------
    G|--9--9-----9-----9-----9--
    D|--------------------------
    A|--------------------------
    E|--0-----------9-----------
```

Comment: Ok, in that case, I would play it as you did except bar the initial E6 chord with the 3rd finger. But that's really a minor point of personal preference